$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x+ \varepsilon u) \frac{1}{1+u^2}du = f(x).$
Let $f$ be a continuous and Lebesgue integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| dx \le \infty$. Consider $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x+ \varepsilon u) \frac{1}{1+u^2}du = f(x).
\end{equation}
I know this can be shown using the dominated convergence theorem, but I have trouble looking for the dominating function. Initially, I thought that $f$ is bounded a.e., but it is incorrect.
Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

This is a so-called approximation-of-unity, with the background that the Dirac delta is the unit of convolution. Split $\Bbb R$ into $[-1,1]$ and the rest and find different means of bounding for the parts.

@geetha290krm The assumptions are given just as in the question. If we have boundedness here, it is easy.

@LutzLehmann  Thanks for your comments. The integral in the question comes from a proof of the Fourier inversion theorem.  The proof I am studying only mentions the DCT theorem to verify the convergence of the integrals. Is there any way to use the DCT directly?

Assume that you know it for $f$ continuous with compact support. Let $\varepsilon'>0$. We will show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every
$0<\varepsilon<\delta$:
$$\left|\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+\varepsilon u)\frac{1}{1+u^2}du-f(x)\right|<\varepsilon'$$
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions with compact support such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$. Up to moving to a subsequence, we can assume that also $f_n\to f$ a.e.
By the triangle inequality:
$$\left|\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+\varepsilon u)\frac{1}{1+u^2}du-f(x)\right|\leq |\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+\varepsilon u)\frac{1}{1+u^2}du-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x+\varepsilon u)\frac{1}{1+u^2}du|+$$
$$+\left|\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x+\varepsilon u)\frac{1}{1+u^2}du-f_n(x)\right|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $n$ be large enough such that that first summand and last summand are less than $\frac{\varepsilon'}{3}$. By assumption, for this specific $n$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<\varepsilon<\delta$ then the second summand is less that $\frac{\varepsilon'}{3}$. To conclude, for this $\delta$, for every $0<\varepsilon<\delta$:
$$\left|\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+\varepsilon u)\frac{1}{1+u^2}du-f(x)\right|<3\cdot\frac{\varepsilon'}{3}=\varepsilon'$$
as desired. Now you need to prove the claim for compactly supported $f$. But this implies $f$ is bounded, and you said you know to solve this case.

I got it. Thanks for your answer.
